# Node/ MySql not working when I try to INSERT data into a newly create column to the database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am working on my first MySQL/ Nodejs project.  I have the following lines of code that are working correctly.

```
async insertNewBrand(brand) {
    try {
        const dateAdded = new Date();
        const insertId = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const query = "INSERT INTO wines (brand, date_added) VALUES (?,?);";

            connection.query(query, [brand, dateAdded] , (err, result) => {
                if (err) reject(new Error(err.message));
                resolve(result.insertId);
            })
        });
        return {
            id : insertId,
            brand : brand,
          
            dateAdded : dateAdded
            
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

When I try to include a new parameter, the code breaks (new code below).  Here I am trying to add *varietal* but adding that in all the needed locations seems to break the code.

```
async insertNewBrand(brand,varietal) {
    try {
        const dateAdded = new Date();
        const insertId = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const query = "INSERT INTO wines (brand, varietal, date_added) VALUES (?,?,?);";

            connection.query(query, [brand, varietal, dateAdded] , (err, result) => {
                if (err) reject(new Error(err.message));
                resolve(result.insertId);
            })
        });
        return {
            id : insertId,
            brand : brand,
          
            dateAdded : dateAdded
            
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I am getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertId')".  I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You must be getting an error, what does `err.message` say?

Comment: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertId')".

Comment: That's not `err.message`, that's because you're trying to use `result.insertId` when there has been error.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error in the SQL, which is being reported by `reject(err.message)`. When there's an error, you shouldn't try to use the `result` object. So use `else` so you either reject or resolve, but not both.

```
            connection.query(query, [brand, varietal, dateAdded] , (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(new Error(err.message));
                } else {
                    resolve(result.insertId);
                }
            })
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see what you mean now.  I adjusted the code and the error message I am getting is "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'varietal' cannot be null".  I have hard coded varietal to hold the value of red in the database.

Comment: This sounds like a problem in the caller of the function, it's not passing a value for the `varietal` parameter.

Comment: You could add a default value to the function: `async insertNewBrand(brand,varietal = "red")`